# how to use 'save' command in matlab as an indexable command

Tags: matlab, indexing, save, wavelet

There is a matrix of 2550*720 dimension. Each row of this matrix is changed to an image by wavelet transform. The problem is that 'save' command in matlab, store  all of 2550 images together in one image.The question is how to indexing 'save' command to store these images separately?
Thank you

```
clc;
clear;
close all;
load P300
load nP300
t = 1:100;
waveletname = 'db1';
P300_cwavelet=[];
ext = '.txt';
for i = 1 : size(P300,1)  
  y = cwt(P300(i,:),t,waveletname);
  P300_cwavelet = [P300_cwavelet;y];
  save('P300_cwavelet','P300_cwavelet');
end
```

Comment: You want to save `y`, right?

Comment: if you want to save each slice of y in separate files, you can do `save(sprintf('y%d',i),'y')`. this saves each y into a file named `y1.mat`, `y2.mat` .... Instead of doing this, you can move your  `save('P300_cwavelet','P300_cwavelet')` line outside of your for-loop, this saves the concatenated `P300_cwavelet` into a single file.

Comment: slice the variable beforehand (assigning it to a new name). MATLAB uses *lazy copying*, i.e. it just points at the new variable without using additional memory until you actually change a value of the new variable

Answer (score 0):

From your question and your code it looks like you have an input matrix that is 720 columns, but you want to store the wavelet transform one per column. You can do that by saving `y` in the for loop.

Your result array `P300_cwavelet` contains all columns `y` at the end of the for loop. You can save the complete result as well by only saving `P300_cwavelet` only once: after the for loop.